How do I test an Angular component that extends a base class with an object in Jest?
I have a base class like this:
    export class TableBase<TData>
  implements OnInit, OnDestroy, AfterViewInit, OnDestroy
{
  @ViewChildren(NgbdSortableHeader) headers: QueryList<NgbdSortableHeader>;

and a component like this:
    export class MasterdataGlobalComponent extends TableBase<IMasterdataGlobalItem> {
  @ViewChildren(NgbdSortableHeader) headers: QueryList<NgbdSortableHeader>;

It seems all other tests are working but I get this error which I assume is for the TData object part:
NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(Standalone[MasterdataGlobalComponent])[[object Object] -> [object Object] -> [object Object]]:
  NullInjectorError: No provider for [object Object]!

What would be the best way to  define/pass this object?
this  is my current test
jest.mock('../../../framework/common/services/auth.service');
import { AuthenticationService } from '../../../framework/common/services/auth.service';
import { ArticleService } from '../../../app/inventory/articles/article.service';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpClientTestingModule } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { provideMockStore } from '@ngrx/store/testing';
import {
  TranslateModule,
  TranslateLoader,
  TranslateFakeLoader
} from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { ToastrModule } from 'ngx-toastr';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/internal/BehaviorSubject';
import {
  MockAuthenticationService,
  MockMasterdataGlobalItem
} from '../../mocks/mocks';

import { MasterdataGlobalComponent } from './masterdata-global.component';
import { MasterdataGlobalItemsService } from './masterdata-global-items-service';
import { TableBase } from '../../../framework/common/table/table-base';
import { IMasterdataGlobalItem } from './masterdata-global-item.interface';
import { NgbdSortableHeader } from '../../../framework/common/table/sortable.directive';

// jest.mock('../../../framework/common/services/auth.service', () => ({
//   AuthenticationService: {
//     currentUser$: new BehaviorSubject<any>({
//       config: [
//         { setting: 'rowsPerPage', value: '10' } // Adjust as needed
//       ]
//     })
//   }
// }));

class MockTableBase extends TableBase<any> {
  constructor() {
    super(null, null, '', null);
  }

  // Override methods or properties used by MasterdataGlobalComponent here
  // For example:
  ngOnInit() {}
  ngOnDestroy() {}
  // Implement other methods or properties as needed
}

// Mocking the PlantSwitched observable
const mockPlantSwitched = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);

// Mocking the UserPlantsService
jest.mock('../../../framework/common/services/user-plants.service', () => ({
  UserPlantsService: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({
    activatedUserPlant$: new BehaviorSubject<any>(null)
  }))
}));

jest.mock('../../../app/inventory/articles/article.service', () => ({
  ArticleService: {
    // Mocked methods or properties as needed
  }
}));

// jest.mock('../../../framework/common/table/table-base', () => ({
//   TableBase: MockTableBase
// }));

// Mock data for testing
const mockData: IMasterdataGlobalItem[] = [
  // Define mock items here
];
describe('MasterdataGlobalComponent', () => {
  let component: MasterdataGlobalComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<MasterdataGlobalComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        MasterdataGlobalComponent,
        NgbdSortableHeader,
        HttpClientTestingModule,
        TranslateModule.forRoot({
          loader: {
            provide: TranslateLoader,
            useClass: TranslateFakeLoader
          }
        }),
        ToastrModule.forRoot()
      ],
      providers: [
        { provide: AuthenticationService, useClass: MockAuthenticationService },
        provideMockStore({}),
        {
          provide: MasterdataGlobalItemsService,
          useValue: MasterdataGlobalItemsService
        },

        { provide: TableBase, useClass: MockTableBase }
      ]
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    (window as any).PlantSwitched = mockPlantSwitched;
    const dataSubject = new BehaviorSubject<IMasterdataGlobalItem[]>([]);
    Object.defineProperty(MasterdataGlobalComponent.prototype, 'data$', {
      get: jest.fn(() => dataSubject.asObservable())
    });

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MasterdataGlobalComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
    // Set the mock data
    dataSubject.next(mockData);
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});

Above is the test of what I currently have . The baseclass is the only thing different from other  component i have which tests are working
